# Adding a constructor using an overloaded operator

Tags: c++

I am working with a linked bag and need to create a copy of the bag using an overloaded operator. The current code is giving me a blank bag. It should be returning the values I put into it with a text file. The problem is with the operator I am trying to overload.

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType>::LinkedBag(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& aBag)
{
    itemCount = aBag.itemCount;
    Node<ItemType> *origChainPtr = aBag.headPtr;

    if (origChainPtr == nullptr)
    {
        headPtr = nullptr; // original bag is empty; so is copy
    } else
    {
        // copy first node
        headPtr = new Node<ItemType>();
        headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());
        headPtr->setCount(origChainPtr->getCount());

        // copy remaining nodes
        Node<ItemType> *newChainPtr = headPtr;
        origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
        while (origChainPtr != nullptr)
        {
            // get next node values from original chain
            ItemType nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();
            int      nextCount = origChainPtr->getCount();

            // create a new node containing the next 2D point
            Node<ItemType> *newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(nextItem, nextCount);

            // link new node to end of new chain
            newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

            // advance pointers
            newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();
            origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
        }
        newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);
    }
} // end copy constructor
```

This the overload operator I am trying to create that 
will create a deep copy of the Linkedbag.

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType>& LinkedBag<ItemType>::operator=(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        this->clear(); // Deallocate left-hand side
        //copyBagNode(rhs); // Copy list nodes
        Node<ItemType> *origChainPtr = rhs.headPtr;
        itemCount = rhs.itemCount; // Copy size of list
    } // end if

 // end operator=
    return *this;   // by convention, operator= should return *this
}
```

Comment: hi. you copy the rhs.headPtr to a local variable named origChainPtr, but you should copy that to headPtr of this

Comment: So to copy the list of nodes what would I need to do?

Comment: @GeraltofRivia supposing the copy constructor works you can define the operator= from it, I did in my answer

Comment: Present your [MCVE] please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is said in a remark by Ali `rhs.headPtr` is not copied into `this->headPtr`, can be something like, from copy constructor definition

```
template<class ItemType>
LinkedBag<ItemType>& LinkedBag<ItemType>::operator=(const LinkedBag<ItemType>& rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        this->clear(); // Deallocate left-hand side

        itemCount = rsh.itemCount;
        Node<ItemType> *origChainPtr = rsh.headPtr;

        if (origChainPtr == nullptr)
        {
          headPtr = nullptr; // original bag is empty; so is copy
        } else
        {
          // copy first node
          headPtr = new Node<ItemType>();
          headPtr->setItem(origChainPtr->getItem());
          headPtr->setCount(origChainPtr->getCount());

          // copy remaining nodes
          Node<ItemType> *newChainPtr = headPtr;
          origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
          while (origChainPtr != nullptr)
          {
            // get next node values from original chain
            ItemType nextItem = origChainPtr->getItem();
            int      nextCount = origChainPtr->getCount();

            // create a new node containing the next 2D point
            Node<ItemType> *newNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>(nextItem, nextCount);

            // link new node to end of new chain
            newChainPtr->setNext(newNodePtr);

            // advance pointers
            newChainPtr = newChainPtr->getNext();
            origChainPtr = origChainPtr->getNext();
          }
          newChainPtr->setNext(nullptr);
        }
    }    
 // end operator=
    return *this;   // by convention, operator= should return *this
}
```

but that duplicate code, better to use a shared additional operation doing the job

Comment: That works for copping the nodes but it crashed my program. It gives me this error Exception thrown: read access violation.
_Pnext was 0xDDDDDDE1.

Comment: @GeraltofRivia which version of my answer did you used ? the new one ?

Comment: The old one. I the new one does not crash. Thanks